# Is there a Winforms implementation of chromes most visited page?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

Im actually trying to make a control, which acts like the chromes most visited page(Screenshot e.g. here: http://www.favbrowser.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/googlechrome15.jpg), which automatically center, resize and move the controls(in my program)/pages(in chrome) if the window was resized.
I know that I could take a `FlowLayoutPanel` or a `TabelLayoutPanel` to implement this, but this would take much time espacially for the resize and moving part.
So my question is: Is there already an open source/free Control which features sth like that?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use a ListView.  It is free.